# Android: Select spinner next item upon clicking the button

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hello guys I need some help with this problem.

[image]

For example, if I press the "ALL PRESENT" button the spinner will select the next item and execute a process and then move to the next item etc. etc.  In other words it is continuous with just a single button click.

Although I already know the code for the next item but I can't figure it out as my basis.

This is my code for the next item:

```
public void spinNext(){
   int nextIndex = spinnerStudent.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;
   if (nextIndex < studentList.size()){
        spinnerStudent.setSelection(nextIndex);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void spinNext(){
    try {
        int nextIndex = spinnerStudent.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;
        if (nextIndex < studentList.size()){
            spinnerStudent.setSelection(nextIndex);
        }else{
            //spinnerStudent.setSelection(0);
            try{
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }catch(Throwable e){
                LogUtils.e("test","spinNext",e);
            }
        }
    }catch (Throwable e){
        LogUtils.e("test","spinNext",e);
    }
}
private Timer timer;

public void onBtnClick(){
    try {
        if(timer!=null){
            try {
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }catch (Throwable e){
                LogUtils.e("test","onBtnClick2",e);
            }
        }
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        spinNext();
                    }
                });
            }
        },0,1000);
    }catch (Throwable e){
        LogUtils.e("test","onBtnClick1",e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(timer!=null){
        try {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }catch (Throwable e){
            LogUtils.e("test","ondestroy",e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello sir thank you for your response but I can't quietly understand this XD maybe, can you explain to me what's this all about? :)

Comment: Copy my code into your code . And btn.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener(){  public void onClick(View view){ onBtnClick()} }).

Comment: oh got it, but it seems it didn't answer my problem :(

Comment: Don't you want when you click a btn,spinner turn to item1->item2->item3 ->item4->item5?

Comment: exactly upon clicking the button the spinner select the next item after executing a certain process. but when I test your code nothings happened and it's just move back to the previous activity.

Comment: I edited it. Plz try and provide errorlog if error occurs.

Comment: hi sir still nothing's happen, after i click the button it's just going back to the previous activity. and there is no error

Comment: spinnerStudent  and studentList is not null?

Comment: I add Try catch in all place.Can you try it again?

Comment: its okay now but I have an slight problem ^_^, when the spinner reach the last item. it moves back to the first item it is like become a cycle ^_^. I want it to stop when the spinner reach the last item